# Flutter : firebase filteration

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am new to flutter and I was retrieving data through google's firebase.
I encountered an error.

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: type
>   'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

The code according to me was correct.

```
  var url = "https://<MyFirebaseProjectId>.firebaseio.com/products.json?auth=$authToken&orderBy='creatorId'&equalTo='$userId'"
```

but when I swapped, single inverted commas and double inverted commas, the code worked correctly.

```
 var url = 'https://<MyFirebaseProjectId>.firebaseio.com/products.json?auth=$authToken&orderBy="creatorId"&equalTo="$userId"'
```

I am not understanding this behavior as both code snippet should work properly.

**Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Flutter/Dart may accept both single and double quotes as string delimiters, the Firebase REST API only accepts double quotes.

So while both of your snippets may look the same to Dart/Flutter, the Firebase server doesn't recognize the `'` character in the first snippet as string delimiters and doesn't know what to do with the parameters because of that.

The solution is to always use `"` inside the string, and thus use `'` as your (outer) string delimiter in your Flutter/Dart code.